Random Walks on Lattices - EW Montroll
I am reading the paper "Random Walks on Lattice - II" by E W Montroll. The paper relates the first passage time to being at state $s$ after $n$-steps. The paper denotes $P_n(s)$ as the probability of being at location $s$ on a lattice of $d$-Dimensions after $n$ steps. $F_n(s)$ as the first passage time to $s$.
We assume that the Random Walker starts at the origin $s = 0$.
The paper goes on to relate $P_n(s)$ to $F_n(s)$. This is the reasoning the paper uses to relate them "If the Random walker is at step $n$, he must have first reached there at some step $j$ and then returned to $s$ in $n-j$ steps. Then goes on to write the relation,
$P_n(s) = \delta_0(s) \delta_0(n) + \sum_{i=1}^n F_i(s) P_{n-i}(0)$.
Here $\delta$ is the usual delta function.
$ \delta_0(s) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \mbox{ if } s = 0 \\
0  & \mbox{ if } s \ne 0 \end{array}\right.$
Now I am a bit stumped here. Does the Author mean that "If the walker was at state $s$ at step $n$, he would have hit $s$ at some prior step $j$ and then returned?. If so the subsequent relation he writes down for $P_n(s)$ and $F_n(s)$ seems wrong. Since he starts at zero $P_{n-i}(0)$ seems like return time to $0$. I would have thought this would be $\sum_i P_{n-i}(s) F_n(s) + \delta_0(s) \delta_0(n)$.
I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me a bit more clearly.

I'm not sure what difference you intend between your version and the author's version. $P_m(0)$ is the probability, starting from $0$, to be at $0$ after $m$ steps. By translation invariance, it is also the the probability, starting from $s$, to be at $s$ after $m$ steps. So the probability to hit $s$ for the first time at time $i$, and then also to be at $s$ at time $n$ (which is $n-i$ steps later than $i$), is $F_i(s)P_{n-i}(0)$. To get the overall probability of being at $s$ at time $n$ (if $s$ is not the origin) we sum this expression over $i$ from $1$ to $n$. Does that help?

@Burbank, that answers my question. The point is translation invariance. So the point is that if it is at $s$ after $n$ steps, it is essentially arriving at $s$ for the first time in $i$ steps and revisiting $s$ again in $n-i$ steps. The confusion resulted because, I would have written it as $\sum_{i=1}^n F_i(s) P_{n-i}(s)$. So what you said cleared it for me. However, this requires a symmetry of sorts right?  The translation invariance. In this case, he makes periodicity assumptions, so $P_{n-i}(s)  = P_{n-1}(0)$?

OK! (but in fact the last thing you write doesn't look quite right. As it stands, $P_m(s)$ means the probability to reach $s$ in $m$ steps starting from $0$. Maybe to express what you mean, you need notation that indicates both starting and ending sites. Let $P_m(a,b)$ be the probability of being at site $b$ after $m$ steps, starting from $a$. Then you have $P_m(s,s)=P_m(0,0)$. More generally, $P_m(a, a+x)=P_m(b,b+x)="P_m(x)"$ for any $m, a,b,x$. This comes from the definition of the RW on the lattice. Something similar holds for many commonly-studied models of random walks on groups.)

@Burbank, You are right, the assumption is that we start at $0$. I stated this explicitly. So I see what you are saying, $P_n(s) = P_n(0,s) = P_n(s, 0)$ maybe the notation can be improved. Also, this symmetry is by definition for the random walk on a lattice. I got it. Thank you again.

@Burbank, I thought some more as I went to rewrite my notes. I understand correctly what you are saying and the error in my logic. 1. $P_n(s)$ is probability of reaching $s$ in $n$ steps starting at $0$. This means that $P_n(0)$ is returning to $0$ in n-steps. This by translation invariance is the same as returning to $s$ if you started from $s$. Which is exactly what the hitting time decomposition is doing. You hit $s$ in $i$ steps and return in $n-i$ steps.
